# TypeError when importing mongoose npm module in React app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, mongoose

In my react project, within a component, I want to include a npm module like so:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', {useNewUrlParser: true});
```

This does work in regular node js, react however shows a `TypeError: mongoose.connect is not a function`. Trying `import mongoose from 'mongoose'` returns a `TypeError: mongoose__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4___default.a.connect is not a function`.

How do I use npm packages in a react app? Do I need meteor (I've heard of it, but I don't understand what it does)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't use mongoose in the browser in anything other than validation => [doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/browser.html)

> Mongoose supports creating schemas and validating documents in the browser. Mongoose's browser library does not support saving documents, queries, populate, discriminators, or any other Mongoose feature other than schemas and validating documents.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to access data from a mongodb from the browser?

Comment: you can't do that in the client side, you have to go through a backend like nodejs